# Unpacking object to display it's content with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

On this page you can order tickets by clicking on the list items.
Clicked items get grouped and then put in an empty  container
on the page. I added a sample view to clarify what the result should
be.

At this point I am stuck. I’m able to insert objects, but I don’t know
how to unpack whats inside the object. That should be the tickets
one clicked. Hopefully someone here can point me in the right
direction to solve this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
        /*  Styling bullets list items */
        li {
            list-style: none;
        }

        li:before {
            content: "\1F3B8";
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        /* Styling for tickets ordered */
        #order {
            background-color: #b0c4de;
            font-size: 120%;
        }
        .sample {
            background-color: #b0c4de;
            font-size: 120%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Here you'll find the prices for the tickets:</p>

<ul>
    <li onclick="push(tckt1)">Saturday: €110</li>
    <li onclick="push(tckt2)">Sunday: €110</li>
    <li onclick="push(tckt3)">Monday: €110</li>
    <li onclick="push(tckt4)">Weekend: €230</li>
</ul>
<div id="order">

</div>
<br>
// This is a sample of how the output should look.
<div class="sample">
    Your order:<br>
    3 Weekend-tickets à €230 = € 690<br>
    1 Sunday-tickets à €110 = € 110<br>
    Totaalbedrag: €800 - 10% korting à €80 = €720
</div>
<script>
  const order = document.getElementById("order")
  let tickets = [];
  const tckt1 = { id: 1, name: "Saturday-tickets à €110", price: 110 };
  const tckt2 = { id: 2, name: "Sunday-tickets   à €110", price: 110 };
  const tckt3 = { id: 3, name: "Monday-tickets   à €110", price: 110 };
  const tckt4 = { id: 4, name: "Weekend-tickets  à €230", price: 230 };

  // Push object in array tickets
  function push(temp) {
    tickets.push(temp);
    let res = tickets.reduce(function(x, cur) {
      let item = cur.id + cur.name + cur.price
      if (!x[item]) x[item] = 0;
      x[item] = x[item] + 1
      return x
    }, {})
    let results = []

    for (const key in res) {
      const count = res[key];
      const id = key.slice(0, 1)
      const day = key.slice(1, 24)
      const price = key.slice(24)
      results.push({
        id: id,
        name: day,
        price: price,
        count: count
      })
    }
    console.log(results)
    order.innerHTML += results[0];
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: it is generally [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) to use inline event handlers. The next snippet uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to handle the clicks.

Second, i have refactored your code a bit. For identifying the originator of a click, it uses a [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). After clicking the
accessory ticket definition is pushed to an array (`savedTickets`). That array is aggregated to an `Object` (`orders`) containing the total values, using ticket definitions name property as keys). From that, the result (`div#orders`) is filled, using [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). Text is aggregated using [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Third: I've used dutch language ;)

Fourth (for fun): [here is a snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-2pok8r?file=script.js) retrieving the necessary values from data-attributes.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, pushTicketAndShowResult);
const [savedTickets, tickets, discount] = initializeValues();

function pushTicketAndShowResult(evt) {
  if (!evt.target.dataset.ticket) {
    return;
  }

  const ticket = tickets[`tckt${evt.target.dataset.ticket}`];
  savedTickets.push(ticket);
  const orders = savedTickets.reduce((acc, t) => {
    acc[t.name] = acc[t.name] || {};
    acc[t.name].n = (acc[t.name].n || 0) + 1;
    acc[t.name].total = acc[t.name].n * t.price;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const result = document.querySelector(`#orders`);
  const total = Object.values(orders).reduce( (acc, o) => acc + o.total, 0);
  const discountAmount = total * discount/100; 
  const totalWithDiscount = total - discountAmount;
  const yourOrders = Object.entries(orders)
    .map( ([name, val]) => `${val.n} ${name} = €${val.total},--`)
    .join(`<br>`)    
    
  result.textContent = ``;
  result.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, `<b>Uw bestelling</b><br>${
    yourOrders}<br>Totaalbedrag: €${total},--<br>Korting ${
      discount}% = €${discountAmount},--<br><b>U betaalt €${
        totalWithDiscount},--</b>`);
}

function initializeValues() {
  return [
    [], {
      tckt1: {
        id: 1,
        name: "zaterdag-ticket(s) à €110,--",
        price: 110
      },
      tckt2: {
        id: 2,
        name: "zondag-ticket(s) à €110,--",
        price: 110
      },
      tckt3: {
        id: 3,
        name: "maandag-ticket(s) à €110,--",
        price: 110
      },
      tckt4: {
        id: 4,
        name: "weekend-ticket(s) à €230,--",
        price: 230
      }
    },
    10
  ];
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:before {
  content: "\1F3B8";
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#order {
  background-color: #b0c4de;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.sample {
  background-color: #b0c4de;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<p>Ticketprijzen. Klik op een prijs om te bestellen:</p>

<ul>
  <li data-ticket="1">Zaterdag: €110,--</li>
  <li data-ticket="2">Zondag: €110,--</li>
  <li data-ticket="3">Maandag: €110,--</li>
  <li data-ticket="4">Weekend: €230,--</li>
</ul>
<div id="orders">
</div>
```